# OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error python while generating big text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hello i'm using the following python script to generate a list of combinations but after 20min or about 2gb generated I get "OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error"

My code:

```
with open(selectedreplacelist, 'r', encoding="ISO-8859-1") as replacemes:
    for replaceme in replacemes:
        replaceme = replaceme.rstrip('\n')
        if ('(kw)' in replaceme) or ('(KW)' in replaceme):
            with open(selectedkeywordlist, 'r', encoding="ISO-8859-1") as keywords:
                for keyword in keywords:
                    keyword = keyword.rstrip('\n')
                    kwps.write(re.sub(r'(?i)\(kw\)', keyword, replaceme + "\n"))
        else:
            kwps.write(replaceme + "\n")
```

extra info:
Running ubuntu 18, someone else tried on windows and it worked fine
kwps = txt file it saves the generated cobinations to on my new samsung t5 ssd

Comment: We're gonna need a [mcve]. What's `kwps`? Also, how many lines do these 2 text files have?

Comment: 2GB isn't there some filesystem limit in some old filesystems?

Comment: i use ubuntu , i dont know whats going wrong because someone else  generated a 20gb file without any problems

Comment: @Aran-Fey the input file has around 5mil lines the output (kwps) is 500mil - 1bil
kwps stands for keyword proccessing